# WFFM MVC and WFFM Webforms in the same instance

Tags: wffm, mvc, webforms

Has anyone tried this? Is this possible?
Do they interfere with each other in any way?

We have a legacy Sitecore instance with many sites on it. The plan is to move them to MVC one by one. But WFFM needs to be available for all sites, so I need to know if this approach is viable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can confirm that it works on Sitecore 7.2 as well as Sitecore 8.2 (we have upgraded along the way).

We have a multisite installation with 4 sites running MVC and the last site being Webforms. We're using WFFM on 1 MVC site and the webforms site without any issues (we're not sharing any specific forms between the 2 sites though).

Answer (score 2):

I had same question to support if Wffm Mvc and Wffm Web Forms can coexist in a Mvc Application. 
Their answer was they can coexist but with limitation :

1. for one item - use the CSHTML layout, views, View Renderings and Controller Renderings;
2. for another item - in the same solution, presentation can be used with the ASPX layout, ASCX controls and XSLT renderings;
3. however, you should never mix pure ASP.NET layout/renderings with MVC layout/renderings in Presentation details of the same item (only ASP.NET or MVC per content item).