# Can we use WFFM rendering and MVC rendering together in same page?

Tags: wffm, mvc-forms

We are using Sitecore 8.1 MVC application.

Our one team member come across issue while using  `WFFM` rendering and `MVC` rendering together in same page.

When clicking on `WFFM` action button it is hitting action but reloading `raw` html page as below:

[image]

It seems we can't mix both `WFFM` and `MVC` renderings together in same page.

Please suggest.

Comment: Which version of Sitecore, WFFM and MVC do you use?

Comment: We are using Sitecore 8.1.

Comment: Isn't this duplicate of https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/7672/wffm-mvc-and-wffm-webforms-in-the-same-instance ?

Comment: @Peter thanks, No this is different thread, here we are facing issue with MVC Instance where issue with using both WFFM and MVC rendering in same page.  But yours link it is for using MVC and Webform.

Comment: If you have the right version of WFFM installed there should be no issues with that. Any of the 8.1 versions should be just fine with MVC